# Getting Filenames of the last X Files of Directory by NAME

Tags: c#, image, directory

i am currently saving filenames with the following name:

```
"Image_from" +  DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd-HH_mm_ss") + ".jpg",
```

In order to do some statistics i want to get the filenames of the last X (e.g. 5) Files. I know i can sort them by last written/edited with:

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\MyDirectory");
var myFile = directory.GetFiles()
             .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
             .First();
```

But if someone changes the File and saves it again, i wont get the "newest created" just the newest edited... 
I want to make sure that i always get the last Files creation wise of specific Directory.

Anyone can help me with that? / has an idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Greeetings,
christian

Comment: Use file info, and return last updated date and sort by that

Comment: You could also sort by file name, since they contain the creation time

Comment: @vyrp , the OP said that wouldnt help if the files had been changed since creation

Comment: On the contrary. His answer doesn't work because he is using `LastWriteTime`. He doesn't want to get the last updated files. He wants the last created times. So using the filename or FileInfo.CreationTime _will_ work.

Comment: @vyrp But only if noone changes that information ;o)

Comment: Oh, I forgot about renaming. Then the only solution is FileInfo.CreationTime then.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies! the Problem i have left is that i need to read more than just the last file... my current attempt=
List<string> dataList = new List<string>();
            string folder = @"C:\";
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.jpg").OrderBy(f => f); ;
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
                var fileinfo = new FileInfo(file);
                long fileSize = fileinfo.Length;
            }
doesnt sort them, but contains every file =/

Comment: Got it working:             string folder = @"C:\\\Downloads\";
            var orderedFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folder).Select(f => new FileInfo(f)).OrderByDescending(f => f.Name);
            foreach (var file in orderedFiles)

THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Name of file, if contains date

```
"Image_from" +  DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd-HH_mm_ss") + ".jpg"
```

like that:

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\MyDirectory");
var myFile = directory.GetFiles()
             .OrderByDescending(f => f.Name)
             .First();
```

Edit:

To get only .csv files, and top 5 create files:

```
            var directory = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\MyDirectory");
            List<FileInfo> files = directory.GetFiles("*.csv").ToList<FileInfo>();

            files.Sort((x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));

            List<FileInfo> top5 = new List<FileInfo>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5 && i < files.Count; i++)
            {
                top5.Add(files[i]);
            }
```

Comment: But as the OP pointed out this doesnt help if someone has changed it since the day it was created

Comment: This answer will work regardless of the files being edited.

Comment: Yes, the files may have been edited as long as they are not renamed.

Comment: Ohh that is great! I am more than fine with that, if someone renames it, the system i build is screwed anyway... So that is oky.

one last things, can i check only for CSV datas for example?`like currently it gets the Names of all Files and sorts them by name, any chance i can filter that for csv-type only?

THANK YOU!

edit: and how can i select higher numbers than "first" for example the 5th newest? (sorry a bit new to programming!)

Comment: Got it working:             string folder = @"C:\\\Downloads\";
            var orderedFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folder).Select(f => new FileInfo(f)).OrderByDescending(f => f.Name);
            foreach (var file in orderedFiles)

THANKS